# Return day from Date in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, date, amazon-redshift, sql-date-functions

Is there a way/function in redshift that returns name of the day from date? For example, if my column is 07/19/2023, it should return Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

Found a function if anyone is interested:

```
select to_char(DATE '2023-07-19', 'DAY')
```